# How do I graph this equation in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

x^4-y^4=0. I want to draw this graph:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: I believe it is not very complicated graph but unfortunately i have no idea how to graph something on latex, i tried to watch some videos and do it but it was useless, so i decided to ask here. I'm pleased if you can help me.

Comment: The point is that everybody here has been a latex newbie. So the idea is not to find the solution yourself if you do not have it, but to show even with a result very far from what you want, that you at least tried something.

Comment: BTW, I believe that is is a graph of $x^4-y^4 \leq 0$, not $|x|=|y|$.

Answer (score 7):

Just that justonly has not the only answer. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,pics/arr/.style={code={\draw[->] (-0.1,0) --
(0.1,0);}}]
 \draw[->] (-4,0) -- (4,0) node[right]{$x$};
 \draw[->] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node[right]{$y$};
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=67.5,distance={8pt}]}] (-pi,pi) -- (0,0) pic[midway,sloped,red]{arr} coordinate (O) -- (-pi,0);
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=-22.5,distance={8pt}]}] (0,pi)  -- (O) -- (pi,pi) pic[midway,sloped,red]{arr};
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=-22.5,distance={8pt}]}] (-pi,-pi)  -- (O) -- (0,-pi); 
 \draw[pattern={Lines[angle=67.5,distance={8pt}]}] (pi,-pi)  -- (O) -- (pi,0); 
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {D_1^+,D_2^+,D_1^-,D_2^-}
 {\path (-22.5+90*\Y:pi+0.6) node{$\X$};
  \draw (-90+90*\Y:1) arc[start angle=-90+90*\Y,end angle=-90+90*\Y+45,radius=1]
   node[midway,anchor=22.5-270+90*\Y]{$\frac{\pi}{4}$};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I actually do not quite understand how these are the solutions to x^4-y^4=0, but I put so many pi's in that it doesn't matter.

Adding the angles and quotes libraries does not make this more elegant.